# JQuery UI Resizable Handlers On Selected Element After Append

Tags: jquery

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/umk8s/

I'm building an experimental website designer using JQuery UI.
Elements are added to the canvas via drag and drop like so...

```
$('.navbar *').draggable({
  //  use a helper-clone that is append to 'body' so is not 'contained' by a pane
  helper: function() {
    return $(this).clone().appendTo('.canvas').css({
      'zIndex': 5
    }).show();
  },
  cursor: 'move',
  containment: "document"
});
$('.canvas, .canvas *').droppable({
  activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
  accept: '.navbar *',
  drop: function(event, ui) { 
    if (!ui.draggable.hasClass("dropped"))
      $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone().removeClass("ui-draggable").removeClass("dropped"));
  }
}).sortable({
  placeholder: 'sort-placer',
  cursor: 'move',
  helper: function (evt, ui) {
    return $(ui).clone().appendTo('.canvas').show();
  }
});
```

However my problem currently resides with resizing an element. (Also with append on a canvas element's container. I'm not asking for assistance on this problem)
I'm trying to only have the resize handlers only show on the selected element, however that's been my problem. I've been having trouble getting it to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$('.canvas *').on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
  $('.canvas *').remove('#nwgrip, #negrip, #swgrip, #segrip, #ngrip, #egrip, #sgrip, #wgrip');
  $(this).append('<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" id="nwgrip"></div> <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" id="negrip"></div> <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" id="swgrip"></div> <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se" id="segrip"></div> <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" id="ngrip"></div> <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" id="egrip"></div> <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" id="sgrip"></div> <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" id="wgrip"></div>');

  $(this).resizable({
    handles: {
      'ne': '#negrip',
      'se': '#segrip',
      'sw': '#swgrip',
      'nw': '#nwgrip',
      'n': '#ngrip',
      'e': '#egrip',
      's': '#sgrip',
      'w': '#wgrip'
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pen - http://codepen.io/mikethedj4/pen/snjpF
Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/umk8s/1/

I ended up using [ThreeDubMedia's](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag/demo/resize2) drag plugin for the resizing effect I wanted.
**NOTE**: I'm still using global variables to save my states.

The initial problem I had with this is when elements were draggable/resizable with [ThreeDubMedia's](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag/demo/resize2) drag plugin I was unable to edit them with contenteditable (it was set to true but the script wasn't allowing any edits). In order to make it editable I had to basically refresh the html. I did this using the script below...

```
$(".code").val( $(".workflow").html() );
$(".workflow").html( $(".code").val() );
```